# Weird if Condition

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on MicroC on Atom 32bit.
I declared 2 tasks with 0x100 stack size (more than enough for my tasks). When I call a function in one of my task, and I check its `if` condition:

```
if (OSSchedLockNestingCtr > (OS_NESTING_CTR)0u) 
{ 
   *p_err = OS_ERR_SCHED_LOCKED;
   return;
}
```

the code goes in even if `OSSchedLockNestingCtr == 0`! I check the esp, and the esp is inside the stack table so I don't have a stack overflow. How is it possible to go inside the `if` branch even if the condition is false?

Comment: Do you have multiple threads/ISRs here that could be modifying things?  Have you stepped through the assembler in the debugger?

Comment: What's the value of `(OS_NESTING_CTR)0u` ? Whatever `OS_NESTING_CTR` is, it might be doing an aritmetic operation with `0u`, rendering it less than `0`.

Comment: @karlphillip:OS_NESTING_CTR is just a define unsigned char.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I have only two tasks, I went through the code assembly : movzbl 0x8b0000,%eax
test %al,%al
je 0x1051e1 <OSTimeDly+45>,  the address of OSSchedLockNestingCtr is 0x108b00, so i don't know where does 0x8b0000 come fomr?

Comment: when you say "it goes in", how are you detecting that?  stepping with debugger, or seeing that the function returns error in *p_err?  If you are stepping with debugger, could it just be a compiler optimization that reorganized things and isn't really going in?  otherwise, step through at the assembly level and see what values are actually getting compared at the register level when it evaluates the > condition

Comment: Add a p/o in your 'If' part of the two vars involved. As described, it obviously shouldn't happen, so probably you are dealing with unexpected values.

Comment: Didn't you check to see if there isn't a stray semi-colon after the if? You probably did check, but I once lost a whole afternoon for such a stray character.

Comment: I find it, the interrupt function was running automatically (5 interrupts in 1 sec) when i was going manual step by step, so how the varaibles were taking others values (interrupt -> ISR -> put some data in the stuck -> back to my Function -> wrierd values :)). 10x to a you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: I find it, the interrupt function was running automatically (5 interrupts in 1 sec) when i was going manual step by step, somehow the varaibles were taking others values (interrupt -> ISR -> put some data in the stuck -> back to my Function -> wierd values :)). 10x to a you all

Comment: Even if you answer your own question, you should still mark it as the correct answer.